# Angular6 issue for ngx-daterangepicker

Tags: angular6

Getting an issue with `ngx-daterangepicker` on **ng serve**

Error message:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker/src/ngx-daterangepicker/ngx-daterangepicker.module.ts
Module build failed: Error: node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker/src/ngx-daterangepicker/ngx-daterangepicker.module.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the .ts files to the **include** section on your **tsconfig.ts** file:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
.....
},
"include": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts",
    "node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker/src/ngx-daterangepicker/index.ts",
    "node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker/src/ngx-daterangepicker/ngx-daterangepicker.component.ts",
    "node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker/src/ngx-daterangepicker/constants.ts",
    "node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker/src/ngx-daterangepicker/ngx-daterangepicker.module.ts",
    "node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker/src/ngx-daterangepicker/ngx-format.pipe.ts"
]
}
```